# difference between CSS selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

What is the difference between `a#add` and `a #add`?

Comment: $('somepart somotherone') matches an element descendant of another one. Please have a look at the documentation of selectors.

Comment: this is definitely a duplicate, just need to find the correct one.....

Comment: `a#add` = `<a id="add">`; `a #add` = `<a>..<someElement id="add">`

Comment: @user2800089 What is the difference between `a #someid { color: green; }` and `a#someid { color: green; }`?

Comment: As ID must be unique, i'd say both are wrong{not really accurate}

Comment: @A.Wolff not really. You may want to match #someid only *when* it's inside a a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a#add` will select `a` tag with `id` as `add`

`a #add` will select elements inside the `a` tag that having id `add`.

Take a look at this page https://stackoverflow.com/tags/css/info

Comment: The only thing I would note is that `a #add` will select ***an*** element inside the `a` tag with an id of `add`. An `id` should be unique to only ***1*** element...

Comment: you are correct, but here, it will only select if the element is inside the `a` tag.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the basics of CSS selectors. The former is a single element, and the latter an ancestor/descendant relationship.